# Extending available space in LVM using LUKS

Tags: fedora, lvm, luks

I have one volume group consisting of `lv_root`, `lv_swap` and `lv_home`. I want to increase the space available to `lv_home` by adding an extra hard drive.

Can this be done while maintaining a LUKS-based hard drive encryption without creating too much interference during usage (automount, same password for both LUKS partition to avoid double password entry, etc..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LVM allows you to "stripe" a logical volume (e.g., your `lv_home`) across many different physical volumes (a.k.a. partitions) easily.  As far as LUKS and the rest of your system are concerned, your logical volume is still one partition so you don't have to worry about any of the other issues you raise.

You can do this either with the graphical `system-config-lvm` application in the Fedora repository or via the command line with the `lvm` tool.